# Yet another "Version in One Place in setuptools Package" - src/ root twist

Tags: python, setuptools

Introducing setuptools package management to my engineering team, and looking to codify best practices in this first package I'm releasing. We're currently doing some PEX bullshit for code that's being run in Docker. I mean, seriously? Each Docker image is supposed to be a snapshot of Python version and code anyways. Do we really need to build a PEX to load into a Docker image? Sigh.

I want the process to be idiot-proof. Not because my fellow engineers are idiots (they're not). But because in general it's simply better to have fewer points for coders and code reviewers to check. Less cognitive load is better.

Anyways, I came across this:

http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/

It recommends putting everything that is to be included in the distribution in `src/`. It eliminates uncertainty for setuptools during `dist` and `sdist`. I agree. This way, we just put `graft src` in `MANIFEST.in`, and we're done. (Though there's the minor problem of excluding `__pycache__`, `*.pyc`, and generated `*.egg-info`, but that's another question.)

Anyways, version number. Where to put it:

1. It needs to be inspectable at runtime, regardless of how the package was installed - `python setup.py develop`, or through setuptools fetching of a source or compiled distribution, regardless of whether it's been compressed or not.

   I obviously can't use `open()`. The `PYTHONPATH` could belong to a package user, in which case paths are relative to that. And what about distributions that are zipped? We basically have to do some `pkg_resource()` madness, which even if we don't use the version str in that call (circular much?), we need to have the package name, which just shifted the "how to DRY" problem from the version to the name. Ugh.

   So even though I don't like polluting the module space, this implies putting `src/<package_path>/_version.py` and `from ._version import __VERSION__` inside of `src/<package_path>/__init__.py`.

But:

2. How do I load this at the point of `python setup.py <something>`?

   Well, I just do:

   ```
   execfile(setuptools.convert_path('src/<package_path>/_version.py'))
   ```

   Then, it's in the `setup.py` global context as `__VERSION__`.

But:

3. Where is `setup.py` being run? As `python setup.py develop`? As `python setup.py install`? Or as `python setup.py dist`? Or is it being run against another package that requires this package?

   The problem is that in `dist`, everything under `src/` gets copied to the root dir. `setup.py` is copied to the root dir. So now the `_version.py` file has moved in relation to `setup.py` for the purposes of installing the dist. So it breaks.

Attempts so far:

1. Override the `install` `cmdclass`. This doesn't work, because in the current structure of `setup.py`, `__VERSION__` is being set *before* `setuptools.setup()` is called. I *could* override the global `cmdclass`, and override the `install` `cmdclass`, so that they each look in different places. But that assumes that installing a dist is different than installing locally (either `develop` or `install`) - I don't see the existence of a `install-dist` type of `cmdclass`, and it assumes that it's safe to modify package version within the execution of `setuptools.setup()` (version is passed in at the call). This seems really complicated and brittle.
2. Simply look for the presence of the `src/` dir. The question is how `setup.py` is called when it's being called by the `install` of a dependent package. I assume the package is copied to some staging area, uncompressed if necessary, and the calling `install` process is actually forking to another `python` so `PYTHONPATH` is right. I haven't looked too far into how `setuptools` is implemented, but this doesn't work, at least on whatever version of `setuptools` is included with Python 3.4.3 as installed by `pyenv`.

Thoughts?

Bonus points:

- Allow changing the `__VERSION__` in a `develop` install to dynamically update the package version. At development time, if the `__VERSION__` is changed, then `pkg_resource()` calls break. Obviously, it's a minor point - I'll just tell my team to look for that and manually reinstall. But eliminating this minor point of cognitive load would be nice.
- We're using CPython 3.4. So whatever solution only needs to work on that. However, I anticipate us open sourcing stuff sometime soon. Compatibility would be nice. (Tox makes it so easy to check!!!)

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Single-sourcing the Project Version](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/single_source_version.html) (but I get the feeling you've already seen that).

Comment: Thanks, @LukasGraf. I did see it, and it's surprising the formal docs are so lackluster. Some of the outlined options don't seem like they would work (I haven't tried most). It does raise questions about if package execution context matters. If I run execfile() inside a module that is in a 3rd party package, how does it interpret paths? It has to do it relative to PYTHONPATH if it's based on a variable passed in from outside the package - how else would wrappers around open() work? But what about literals or expressions based entirely on inside the package? Is Python that smart/unreasonable?